# Why are there more icons in the google-hosted icon font than when I download the icons?

Tags: google-material-icons

Looking at Google material icons [HERE](https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#icon-font-for-the-web), there are two options for accessing these fonts:

1) via CDN
2) self hosted

If I choose self hosted, I include this in my CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Material Icons'),
         local('MaterialIcons-Regular'),
         url('../fonts/material-design-icons/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/material-design-icons/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/material-design-icons/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

However, then I add an icon in my app:

```
<i class="material-icons">money</i>
```

And nothing appears. But if I don't self-host - i.e. I include this in my header:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

Then the money icon appears.

Why do I seem to have more icons if I link to the CDN compared to self hosting the file?

Looking at the codepoints file [HERE](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/blob/master/iconfont/codepoints), it seems that all the code points are available when I self host. Why are there more icons than are available in the codepoints file than from in the icons in the repo?

Comment: For anyone else who comes across this... I was actually using two completely different libraries. stupidly. Easy to get confused though, so I'll leave it up

Comment: I see this issue too, what do you mean by two different libraries?

Comment: Same here, how did you resolve this?

Comment: In my case I downloaded one library and looked at the docs for a different library. I resolved this by looking at docs for the library that I had downloaded instead